# Does Liferay supports IPC for portlets on different pages?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In IBM Websphere for IPC, we have something called as [**Wiring**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.btools.help.monitor.dash.doc/dash/view_coop.html) which allows us to switch to the receiving portlet page in case you have your event receiving portlet to be on different page than that of source portlet.

I am wondering if there is any way to achieve this in Liferay.

I have also followed the link: [Using JSR-268 IPC for portlets on different pages in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741936/using-jsr-268-ipc-for-portlets-on-different-pages-in-liferay) but not clear about *`application-context.xml`* as I have created a simple Liferay plugin-portlet-project from Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP's wiring, but isn't it inherently ambiguous what "the receiving portlet page" is - e.g. this needs to be plural, right? An event can be handled by any number of portlets, they can be on any number of pages. For this reason I prefer to have a more explicit handling of the redirection, but that might not be what you're asking for(?)

Comment: Hi Olaf,

I am curious to know whether following functionality is possible with Liferay or not:
Say if I have portlet X showing some info and publishing event and portlet Y which will receive that event but it is on another page.
On portlet x, I have one link on click of which event will get triggered and the page containing portlet Y will be opened receiving event.
In IBM Websphere, you can define target and receiver whose mapping is stored in DB.
So when I click on link in portlet X it fires event and takes me to page containing portlet Y

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about Websphere, but in Liferay a portlet can reside on more than one page. This means that you don't target a portlet but a portlet-on-a-page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You just need to pass the Layout id, portlet id along with your parameters.

```
<liferay-renderURL var="varLink" plId="layout-id" portletName="portletName_WAR_WarName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wiring is Websphere Portal's concept.
Liferay is not supporting Wiring, but you can do Inter-portlet communication using public render parameters & portlet events ( in case of ACTION->View IPC).

In case when you need (VIEW->VIEW) IPC, you can use liferay's session sharing mechanism.
More details on my blog https://rutvijshah.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/liferay-session-sharing-made-easy/